How to make data class copy with only properties initialized, to avoid StackOverflowError?
I have encountered a problem while trying to resolve problem with sensitive info in application logs — we have quite large data class object that at some time in processing flow we log. Problem is that this object contains properties email and phoneNumber, which we need to mask while logging to avoid leaking this data, for this we have two extension methods: String.maskEmail() and String.maskPhoneNumber().
That was my first solution, during which I encountered StackOverflowError:
data class Foo(
    val email: String = "email",
    val phoneNumber: String = "phoneNumber",
    // consider the fact that there is tens more props in real object
) {
    override fun toString() = withMaskedProps

    private val withMaskedProps: String = copy(
        email = email.maskEmail(), phoneNumber = phoneNumber.maskPhone(),
    ).toString()
}

In hindsight it's obvious, because object at initialization recursively creates the copy, which creates the copy and etc. until we get the error.
The question is — can I achieve desired outcome without SO? I need the copied object to simply access property fields, without initializing anything else to not cause SO. And I want to make it universal, by overriding toString() and by ensuring that I don't need to support new fields in string representation if new properties will be added to the data class.

I'm not a Kotlin developer, but is the problem actually initialization, or is it that toString() creates a new copy, then calls toString() on that copy, which creates a new copy and calls toString() etc? (If you don't call toString(), is everything fine?)

@JonSkeet during initialization, as private val withMaskedProps recursively copies object and throws SO when Foo() is created.

Ah, right. Is there any reason withMaskedProps is a field rather than a method? (Just create a new copy when required, rather than on initialization.) In terms of fixing this, if you include an "isMasked" field somewhere, you could basically make a withMaskedProps() method return this if isMasked is true, and the masked copy otherwise (which would have isMasked true). I don't know enough about Kotlin to know whether that's feasible/idiomatic though. (Ideally you'd want isMasked to effectively be private, and only specified at all when creating the masked copy...)

@entendrious I assume you don't want to hand-write the toString that would have been automatically generated for your data class? If you don't mind hand-writing that, you can just do what Jon Skeet says. Otherwise, consider creating your own PhoneNumber and Email classes, and override toString in those classes.

@JonSkeet The problem with this approach is that toString() will be called recursively: override fun toString(): String = (if (isMasked) this else withMaskedProps()).toString(). As this is the same method it will never return the result. StackOverflowError won''t be on initialization, but on call to a.toString().

@Sweeper never thought of that, but that might be a solution.

@entendrious: Yes, it needs a little more care, but I'd expect it to be feasible, e.g. (in Java syntax) isMasked ? super.toString() : withMaskedProps().toString(). Surely there's some way in Kotlin of overriding toString but still accessing "the result as it would be without the override".

(Ah, I see there isn't, as per Sam's answer.)

@JonSkeet, there is (same as in Java) except in the case of data classes, as there is no superclass defining the toString() that lists all the property values.

Another possible approach would be to make a wrapper class (MaskableString) that allows these properties to be set to masked or not, which would change how their toString() function behaves.

@Sweeper I found your solution to use wrapper classes with overridden '.toString()' methods to be the most practical, If you could, please answer it directly so I can mark it as the most helpful.

Overriding toString in a data class necessarily means that you are giving up the automatically generated implementation. If you don't want to do that, you can create your own PhoneNumber and Email classes that returns masked values from their toString.
@JvmInline
value class PhoneNumber(val value: String) {
    override fun toString() = "XXXX XXXX"
}
@JvmInline
value class Email(val value: String) {
    override fun toString() = "example@example.com"
}

data class Foo(
    val email: Email,
    val phoneNumber: PhoneNumber,
    // ...
)

I have made these value classes so that they get inlined on JVM, but they can also be regular classes or data classes if you prefer.

If I understand correctly, your requirement is really to modify the behaviour of the toString() function. You want it to behave mostly as normal, but with some properties modified or redacted.
The toString() function of a data class is generated for you by the compiler. Unfortunately, there's no way to override toString() while still retaining access to the compiler's generated version. When the compiler sees that you've provided your own implementation, it will skip adding its own.
That means you can't really "mix and match" in the way that you want. As you've discovered, making a copy() will let you redact the properties, but you still need to override toString() to insert that change. At that point, the original generated implementation of toString() is gone, and can't be retrieved.
You can get around it by modifying the compiler's generated toString() implementation, instead of adding an override. To do that, you'll need a compiler plugin. There are at least two plugins designed for this purpose.
For example, using https://github.com/ZacSweers/redacted-compiler-plugin, you could annotate your class or its properties as @Redacted. There's no need to create a copy().
@Retention(SOURCE)
@Target(PROPERTY, CLASS)
annotation class Redacted

data class Foo(
  @Redacted val email: String = "email",
  @Redacted val phoneNumber: String = "phoneNumber",
  …
)

The plugin has plenty of configuration options to let you customize how the redacted data will appear.
There's also a similar https://github.com/aafanasev/sekret plugin.

Change withMaskedProps to not be a property initialized at init.
Make it a getter. It will generate the copy only when withMaskedProps is called.
private val withMaskedProps: String get() = copy(...).toString()

Or make it lazy. It will generate the copy once, only if withMaskedProps is accessed.
private val withMaskedProps: String by lazy { copy(...).toString() }


With this implementation you still can't use .toString() as it will get withMaskedProps that calls .toString() that gets withMaskedProps and so on and so on, so we'll get StackOverflowError.
